# Qt/QML/C++ Application database connection object visibility

Tags: c++, database

I am working on some Qt/QML/C++ app and I've got myself into some kind of dead end. Namely, this app uses mysql database and here is my questions: Is performance hurt if I instantate new database connection for every database query I need or is it better to connect to database at app startup via singleton object and reuse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, performance will be impacted by creating a new connection every time - it's not a zero cost operation. However, is this a *significant* problem for your application? Only you can answer that after having done some profiling.

The answer to this is not to use a singleton though - at some point, your app is almost certainly going to want two simultaneous connections to the database. Look into using some sort of connection pool where you keep a set of connections around and reuse them as appropriate.